# How can I start an interactive bash script from a node app?

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, command-line-interface, inquirerjs

I'm building a command-line app in Node which is basically a setup wizard. At some point in the script, I'd like to start an `openssl` script which has its own stdout and prompts, and then ideally return to my Node app when it's done.

I've tried using `spawn` but am having trouble showing the stdout. Is this practically possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, you can pipe standard input and output to your parent process like this,

```
// Child will use parent's stdios
spawn('yourcommand', [], { stdio: 'inherit' });
```

first parameter is your command, second parameter is command parameters and third parameters is how to handle standard inputs and outputs,

Refer this documentation for more information,
https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio